# Opening and closing section using jQuery Find method

Tags: jquery, find

I am trying to open and close the `section` elements by clicking on the H3 tag. I've tried numerous options now and cannot get the jQuery working. Can someone spot the mistake below please?

```
    <div class="sectiondrop">
    <h3>Download</h3>
    <section>
    <a class="label-en" href="/files/label-eng.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>Label (ENG)</a>
            <a class="label-af" href="/files/_label-afr.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>Label (AFR)</a>
            <a class="label-msds" href="/files/_ds.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>DS</a>
            <a class="label-brochure-1" href="/files/eng.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>Eng Brochure</a>
    </section>
    </div>




    <div class="sectiondrop">
    <h3>Download</h3>
    <section>
    <a class="label-en" href="/files/label-eng.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>Label (ENG)</a>
            <a class="label-af" href="/files/_label-afr.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>Label (AFR)</a>
            <a class="label-msds" href="/files/_ds.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>DS</a>
            <a class="label-brochure-1" href="/files/eng.pdf" target="_blank"><span></span>Eng Brochure</a>
    </section>
    </div>


    jQuery( ".sectiondrop h3" ).click(function() {
        //alert ("hello");
        jQuery(".sectiondrop").find('section').toggle( "slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$(this)` and `.next()`:

```
jQuery(this).next('section').toggle("slow");
```

or with `.siblings()`:

```
jQuery(this).siblings('section').toggle("slow");
```

---

As your markup is saying that `h3` which holds the event of `click` does not have a children or grand-children named `section` so it never finds it.

instead of `.find()` use `.next()` or `.siblings()` because it is an sibling which is available at the same level where your `h3` is.

and also you have to do this in the current context so use `$(this)` to get the elem in the current context.

Comment: They're all right but this worked for me, thanks Jai!

Answer (score 2):

The `section` is the next sibling of the `h3` element, so you need to use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/). [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to fetch the descendant elements

```
jQuery( ".sectiondrop h3" ).click(function() {
    //alert ("hello");
    jQuery(".sectiondrop").next('section').toggle( "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .next() to find the section or nextAll for a more dynamic solution

```
jQuery( ".sectiondrop h3" ).click(function() {
    //alert ("hello");
    jQuery(this).next().toggle( "slow");
});
```

or nextAll

```
jQuery( ".sectiondrop h3" ).click(function() {
    //alert ("hello");
    jQuery(this).nextAll('section:first').toggle( "slow");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KUPw8/)